# Count Data by Loop Calendar SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I need to get the data that generates count of total ID by date between date_active and date_end using date ranges for each. If the dates are crossing each other the ID will adding up. here is the data I have right now,

```
  TABLE CONTRACT:
  ID    DATE_ACTIVE    DATE_END
  1   05-FEB-13      08-NOV-13
  1   21-DEC-18      06-OCT-19
  2   05-FEB-13      27-JAN-14
  3   05-FEB-13      07-NOV-13
  4   06-FEB-13      02-NOV-13
  4   25-OCT-14      13-APR-16

  TABLE CALENDAR:
  DT
  05-FEB-13
  06-FEB-13
  07-FEB-13
  08-FEB-13
  09-FEB-13
  ..-DEC-19
```

what I want out is basically like this:

```
 DT         COUNT(ID)
 05-FEB-13    3
 06-FEB-13    4
 07-FEB-13    4
 08-FEB-13    4
 09-FEB-13    4
 10-FEB-13    4
 ....
 03-NOV-13    3
 ....
 08-NOV-13    2
 09-NOV-13    1
 ....
 28-JAN-14    0
 ....
 25-OCT-14    1
 ....
 13-APR-16    1
 14-APR-16    0
 ....
 21-DEC-18    1
 ....
 06-OCT-19    1
 07-OCT-19    0
 ....
 ....
```

And here is my query to get that result

```
with contract as (
select * from contract
where id in ('1','2','3','4')
)
,
cal as 
(
select TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM) dt
from dual
connect by rownum < sysdate - to_date('05-FEB-13')
)

select aa.dt,count(distinct bb.id)id from cal aa
left join contract bb on aa.dt >= bb.date_active and aa.dt<= bb.date_end
group by aa.dt
order by 1
```

but the problem is I have 6 mio of ID and if I use this kind of query, the result maybe will take forever, and I'm having a hard times to figured out how to get the result with different query. It will be my pleasure if somebody can help me out of this. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you want a row per day in your output, ultimately you need to join to a table with a row for every day. So your query is fine. If it's too slow, you'll need to look at something like materialized views to pre-compute the result.

Comment: If you don't have overlapping date ranges for the same ID, you can remove the distinct from your count, this should help a bit. The other issue is that the join condition precludes CBO from using a hash join. Can you post the exec plan to see what it is doing? Another question: which Oracle version are you using and do you have an index on the date_active column?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon yes, I want to display it by day from 2013 till today, may I know how the  materialized views to pre-compute work?

Comment: @gsalem the problem is, it has the same ID overlapped. What I want to see is how many number of daily contract we have since 2013.

Answer (score 1):

If you group your events by `date_active` and `date_end`, you will get the numbers of events which have started and ended on each separate day.

Not a lot of days have passed between 2013 and 2019 (about 2 000), so the grouped resultsets will be relatively short.

Now that you have the two groups, you can notice that the number of events on each given date is the number of events which have started on or before this date, minus the number of events which have finished on or before this date (I'm assuming the end dates are non-inclusive).

In other words, the number of events on every given day is:

1. The number of events on the previous date,
2. plus the number of events started on this date,
3. minus the number of events ended on this date.

This can be easily done using a window function.

This will require a join between the calendar table and the two groups, but fortunately all of them are relatively short (thousands of records) and the join would be fast.

Here's the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b21ce/5

```sql
WITH    cal AS
        (
        SELECT  TRUNC (to_date('01-NOV-13') - ROWNUM) dt
        FROM    dual
        CONNECT BY
                rownum < to_date('01-NOV-13')- to_date('01-FEB-13')
        ),
        started_on AS
        (
        SELECT  date_active AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt_start
        FROM    contract
        GROUP BY
                date_active
        ),
        ended_on AS
        (
        SELECT  date_end AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt_end
        FROM    contract
        GROUP BY
                date_end
        )
SELECT  dt,
        SUM(COALESCE(cnt_start, 0) - COALESCE(cnt_end, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY dt) cnt
FROM    cal c
LEFT JOIN
        started_on s
USING   (dt)
LEFT JOIN
        ended_on e
USING   (dt)
```

(I used a fixed date instead of `SYSDATE` to keep the resultset short, but the idea is the same)

This query requires that the calendar starts before the earliest event, otherwise every result will be off by a fixed amount, the number of events before the beginning of the calendar.

You can replace the fixed date in the calendar condition with `(SELECT MIN(date_active) FROM contract)` which is instant if `date_active` is indexed.

**Update:**

If your contract dates can overlap and you want to collapse multiple overlapping contracts into a one continuous contract, you can use window functions to do so.

```sql
WITH    cal AS
        (
        SELECT  TRUNC (to_date('01-NOV-13') - ROWNUM) dt
        FROM    dual
        CONNECT BY
                rownum <= to_date('01-NOV-13')- to_date('01-FEB-13')
        ),
        collapsed_contract AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  c.*,
                        COALESCE(LAG(date_end_effective) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_active), date_active) AS date_start_effective
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  c.*,
                                MAX(date_end) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_active) AS date_end_effective
                        FROM    contract c
                        ) c
                ) c
        WHERE   date_start_effective < date_end_effective
        ),
        started_on AS
        (
        SELECT  date_start_effective AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt_start
        FROM    collapsed_contract
        GROUP BY
                date_start_effective
        ),
        ended_on AS
        (
        SELECT  date_end_effective AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt_end
        FROM    collapsed_contract
        GROUP BY
                date_end_effective
        )
SELECT  dt,
        SUM(COALESCE(cnt_start, 0) - COALESCE(cnt_end, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY dt) cnt
FROM    cal c
LEFT JOIN
        started_on s
USING   (dt)
LEFT JOIN
        ended_on e
USING   (dt)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adeba/1

The query might seem bulky, but that's to make it more efficient, as all these window functions can be calculated in a single pass over the table.

Note however that this single pass relies on the table being sorted on `(id, date_active)` so an index on these two fields is crucial.

Comment: I think I cannot use this method since I have overlapping ID, and between their crossing date I want to count it as one.
there is data like this in my table:
ID    date_active    date_end
5      05-FEB-13     19-JAN-14
5      07-MAR-13    18-FEB-14

and between the crossing date, I want to count distinct the ID

Comment: @dedesoetopo: I'm not really sure what an "overlapping id" or a "crossing date" are. My query gives exactly the output you have in your example: when the contracts 1 and 4 expire for the first time, the counter goes down.

Comment: Yes, based on the example I posted, your query is right. And I'm sorry, I'm not included the example for overlapping ID. Here is the example of it.
ID: 5. DATE_ACTIVE: 05-FEB-13. DATE_END: 19-JAN-14.
ID: 5. DATE_ACTIVE: 07-MAR-13. DATE_END: 20-JAN-14. 

if there's data like this, in your query this ID will be count as 2, but what I want is it will be count as 1

Comment: As you have overlapping dates/ids, you can still use Quassnoi's solution, after modifying the started_on inline query like this: started_on AS
        (
        SELECT  date_active AS dt, COUNT(*) AS cnt_start
        FROM    contract c
          where not exists ( select null from contract d where d.id=c.id
                            and d.date_active<c.date_active 
                            and c.date_end>d.date_active)
        GROUP BY
                date_active
        ),

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `row_number() over (order by id,date_active)` analytic function is used in order to generate unique ID values those will be substituted in
`connect by level <= ... and prior id = id` syntax to get unpivoted hierarchical data :

```
with t0 as
(
  select row_number() over (order by id,date_active) as id, date_active, date_end
    from contract
), t1 as
(
  select date_active + level - 1 as dt
    from t0
  connect by level <= date_end - date_active + 1
      and prior id = id
      and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
select dt, count(*) 
  from t1    
 group by dt 
 order by dt
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=235b9cd18ddc2030486c1b0fe4baed9a)</kbd>

Comment: I already tried yours, but I think it still needs a lot of time to get the result. Can you help me what should I do to improve it?